# - Write a function called sumNumbers that accepts a single array of numbers and returns the sum of the numbers in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum

I'm really new to JavaScript, So excuse me if this question might seem a little underwhelming.

I'm trying to write a function that performs the following:

**1. accepts a single array of numbers and returns the sum of the numbers in the array. 2. If empty, returns 0.**

```
let num3 = function sumNumbers([index]) {
if (index != "number") {
    return 0;
}
else {
    [index].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
}


}



num3(1, 2, 3);
```

However, I am getting this error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: number 1 is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
at sumNumbers (main.js:16:31)
at main.js:25:1
```

Anyone know the solution? would really appreciate it :)

Comment: you wrote the function `num3` expecting an Array as the first argument, but call it with `1` as the first argument, which is no iterable (or an Array) - if the function `accepts a single array of numbers` - then it is `num3 = function(arr) {` .... and called like `num3([1,2,3])` - i.e. the opposite of how you wrote it

Comment: Here's fixed code: https://jsfiddle.net/rs46bp9c/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [iterate over the array using a `for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) and increment the `sum` in each iteration and finally return it.

If there are no numbers in the array then the function would return the initial value of `sum`, which is `0`.

```js
function addNums(nums) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    sum += nums[i];
  }
  return sum;
}

console.log(addNums([1, 2, 3]));
console.log(addNums([]));
```

You can also use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and do the calculation in a single step.

```js
const addNums = (nums) => nums.reduce((s, n) => s + n, 0);

console.log(addNums([1, 2, 3]));
console.log(addNums([]));
```

Comment: I don't quite understand why the downvotes for this answer. It is working & has explanation. +1 from me, for the time + efforts gone into this. BTW: `const addNums = (nums) => (nums || []).reduce((s, n) => s + n, 0);` --> and we can avoid the ternary, and handle inputs that are falsy. :-)

Comment: @jsN00b Yeah, I've updated my answer, no need for any conditionals.